Will the component re-render if i change the object property which is initialised with a state in react?
I have a state creditNote and before sending the payload to the api call, I am changing the payload and I can see the changed value for a second in my UI
creditNote state
const [creditNote, setCreditNote] = useState({
    invoiceNo: "",
    data: "Entire",
    creditNoteStatus: "pending",
    creditNoteDate: formatDate(new Date().toLocaleDateString()),
    creditNoteNo: "",
    remarks: "",
  });

const payload = creditNote;
const datearray = creditNote?.creditNoteDate.split("-");
payload.creditNoteDate =datearray[1] + "-" + datearray[0] + "-" + datearray[2];
const res = (await addEntireCreditNote(payload, category)) as any;

I am changing the payload only and not using the setState function so i should not be seeing the date changed in the UI. Even if it is changing the state, will it be causing re-rendering of the component.

"Even if it is changing the state, will it be causing re-rendering of the component." - No, because you are mutating the reference, it won't trigger a component rerender. You should avoid mutating React states at all costs. Are you wanting to ask how to avoid mutating the state reference here for the API call?

yes, I want to change the date format before sending to the backend and I dont want to mutate the react state directly.


Even if it is changing the state, will it be causing re-rendering of
the component.

No, because you are mutating the reference, it won't trigger a component rerender. With const payload = creditNote; the payload variable is a direct reference to the React state, and payload.creditNoteDate = ... is the mutation.
You should avoid mutating React states at all costs.
Create shallow copies of all state, and nested state, that you are updating.
Example:
const [first, second, third] = creditNote?.creditNoteDate.split("-") || [];

const payload = {                                   // <-- new object reference
  ...creditNote,                                    // <-- shallow copy state
  creditNoteDate: [second, first, third].join("-"), // <-- overwrite property
};

const res = (await addEntireCreditNote(payload, category)) as any;

